# Network Manager download

Tags: 10.10, network-manager

Where I can download the Network Manager for Meerkat? (.deb file, please)

Answer (score 2):

You can find it [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/) - it's the Index of /ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager

Answer (score 1):

According to Synaptic Package Manager, [this](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) (gnome.org) is the project homepage. I don't see any .deb files specifically listed, but there are multiple options at the ftp link there. Hope that helps.

Did you try grabbing it right from the Package manager?

Comment: I must have internet connection do grab from the package manager, right?